# In web application, how to store a html page at client side?

Tags: html, angularjs

My web application have many pages, in first page I select an item from select box.Then I move on to second page and again come back to first page with the help of browser back button.Now my page was refreshed and my select box selection was reset to default one.Now my question is when I click the browser back button there is no need to refresh my page.I want the html page from my client side storage with what are the changes I did before.

Comment: Store the data of the page somewhere then

Comment: Since you tagged angularjs, you can either use the $rootScope to store the data of the select box or turn it into a service

Comment: I want to save each page of my web app in local storage, not only the data.
When I click the browser back and forward botton show the page stored at client side .
No need to refresh the page every time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly there is no way to keep a site alive, after you switch the `location`.

You can use the localStorage, to store the data, and read it, when the page is opened.

```
localStorage.setItem("selection", JSON.stringify(data)); 
//@pageOne -> open page two
```

->

```
//@pageOne init
var storageItem = localStorage.getItem("selection"); 
if(storageItem) { 
    var selection = JSON.parse(storageItem);
    //add selection to the content.
}
```

Or as mentioned in the comments the `$rootScope`, but i dont know how you do that.